# very long line causing problems

Tags: awk

I have a problem with a file containing ~80,000 lines. It is a large file of 23Gb. I have managed to chunk up similar files of that size with the following command:

```
awk '{fn = NR % 24;  print > ("file1_" fn)}' file1
```

However, this command stalls on this one problem file. The problem file does have a very large line of 3 billion characters (longest lines in other files are less than 1 billion) and I am guessing this is the problem.

I would like to get rid of this long line from the file and proceed but this is proving difficult. I though simply using the following would work

```
awk 'length < 1000000000' file1 > file2
```

However, this is also still running after 3.5hrs. Is there a fast way of just going through a file and the moment a count for the number of characters in a line exceeds e.g. 1 billion, it stops counting and moves to the next line?

Comment: I don't anything about this problem ('i consider using c for the answer) but it sounds jolly interesting.

Comment: What version of awk are you using (`awk --version`)? Maybe a newer version of GNU awk (gawk) is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try to combine the two awk lines into one command, it could be faster. Because, it processes your monster file only once. But you have to test.

```
awk '{fn = NR % 24;  if(length< 1000000000) print > ("file1_" fn)}' file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using sed to delete lines longer than a certain number of characters

```
# delete lines longer than 65 characters
sed  '/^.\{65\}/d' file
```

You can also use a 2-step approach:

```
# use sed to output the line numbers containing lines
# longer than a certain number of characters
sed -n '/^.\{65\}/=' file
```

and then use that list to build a skip-list in awk, i.e. if `NR` equals any of those numbers, skip that line.